# Display field based on value from picklist

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-process-template

I am using Visual Studio Team Services and wanted to customise my Task work item to display a field based on value from picklist, i.e. if a specific value is selected then display another field which will be mandatory.

If this is not achievable then I guess i can always create a new task template specifically for this but it seems like overkill? Anyone done this?

Answer (score 1):

There is not support for conditional display of fields in the inheritance-based process template customization experience. Support is [planned](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/01/26/team-services-process-customization-roadmap-jan-2017/), however.